# Retrieving the data from PgRouting

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, routing, osm2pgrouting

Currently i have created the layer in Geoserver by configuring a native SQL statement, there i am getting the route geometry details from DB by following query

```
   SELECT ST_MakeLine(route.geom) FROM (
    SELECT geom FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways', %x1%, %y1%, %x2%, %y2%
  ) ORDER BY seq) AS route
```

this will give me linestring but along with this i want some other details i.e name of the node etc for that i just modified the query as

```
 SELECT ST_MakeLine(route.geom),text(route.name) FROM (
    SELECT geom,name FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways', %x1%, %y1%, %x2%, %y2%
  ) ORDER BY seq) AS route
```

name above is nothing but the name of the route and text() will returns me the name if each route.But this gives syntax error.How to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you will have by using `ST_MakeLine(route.geom)` is, that this function aggregates all geometries into one geometry, but you can't do this for the street name attribute for example, because the street name will probably change from road to road.

So if you want to make more attributes available through Geoserver you can't use `ST_MakeLine`.
Instead you can just use

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_fromAtoB('ways', %x1%, %y1%, %x2%, %y2%)
```

But in this case your request will return more than one single linestring and you need to modify the way your route is rendered for example.